# What are proper collocations of 'revision'?

Tags: collocation

Can I say: I will do/make revision of the material that we have covered so far.

Should I say : I will revise  the material that we have covered so far.

Comment: What do you mean by saying material?

Comment: And where is the article? It ought to be: "I will do/make ***a*** revision".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do** revision of the material you've covered so far. You can also **revise** the material that you've covered so far.

More collocations of the word **revision** with its different meanings can be found [here](http://5yiso.appspot.com/). It's a dictionary of collocations for students of English. Just type the word **revision** and take a look at the results.

Comment: Is this British I wonder?  I expect to hear an article with revision: You do a revision, make a revision, prepare a revision, work on a revision, etc.

Comment: @Julia: If you are referring to *doing revision of the material covered so far*, yes, it is [British](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/revision).

Answer (score 2):

**Revision** may possibly collocate with these verbs:

> make, complete, undergo, undertake, approve, recommend, suggest